# FlashDevelop can't install the Android app on device

Tags: android, air, device, flashdevelop

I connect my tablet via Wifi and get install the apk file generated by Adobe Air on it. I install it via "adb install" and it works.

But on FlashDevelop, when I configure to run on device, it's shown "device not found (waiting for device)", while itself lists the device connected (192.168.0.103).

What is wrong?

See the result below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must enable USB debugging on your device.
To do so you need to go to Settings > Developer Options and then tick USB debugging on your device.
Developer options are hidden by default starting with Android 4.2.2.
To unlock developer options on Android 4.2.2 you need to go to Settings > About device >
Hop on down to the build number, and tap it seven times.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: And *then*, at least on my Nexus 7, you have to go back into Settings, and now there will be a "Developer options" section you can tap into. From there, you have to select "USB debugging." It's not turned on automatically after tapping the build number as above.